# How to add custom validaton rule to default Validator::make($data... register in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I have read in the documentation how to create [new custom validation rule](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#custom-validation-rules).

I have made one like the one in the example but to only allow lowercase. The class is creatively named *Lowercase*.

Now I want to add that to the Validator-list in the RegisterController generated from make:auth. This is the list I want to add it to:

```
return Validator::make($data, [
        'name' => 'required|string|max:255|**ADD MY VALIDATOR HERE**',
        'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
    ]);
```

Obviously there is something here I am missing... In the documentation it says to use the one I have done like this:

```
$request->validate([
'name' => ['required', 'string', new Lowercase],
]);
```

What do I need to do to be able to add my custom rule to the list above?

EDIT 1:

Per request I am showing the rule I have created. It is IDENTICALL to the one in the linked example in the documentation but I have switched the name of it from ***Uppercase*** to ***Lowercase*** and ***strtoupper*** to ***strtolower***

```
public function passes($attribute, $value)
{
    return strtolower($value) === $value;
}
```

Comment: Show the rule you created

Comment: Have you tried using an array instead of the pipe style like shown in the documentation? I would think that you can't instantiate a class inside the single quotes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a few options. One would be to use artisan to make a rule

```
php artisan make:rule Lowercase
```

You would end up with app\rules\Lowercase.php which you'd want to look something like this

```
<?php

namespace App\Rules;

use Auth;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Rule;

class Lowercase implements Rule
{
    /**
     * Create a new rule instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
    }

    /**
     * Determine if the validation rule passes.
     *
     * @param  string  $attribute
     * @param  mixed  $value
     * @return bool
     */
    public function passes($attribute, $value)
    {
        return strtolower($value) === $value;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation error message.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function message()
    {
        return 'Must be lowercase!';
    }
}
```

"Once the rule has been defined, you may attach it to a validator by passing an instance of the rule object with your other validation rules:"

So in your RegisterController

```
use App\Rules\Lowercase;

return Validator::make($data, [
    'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255', new Lowercase],
    'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
    'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
]);
```

---

A second option would be to use a closure and not bother making the custom rule with artisan. This works well if you don't really need to use the rule somewhere else.

So in your RegisterController you can do something like this:

```
return Validator::make($data, [
     'name' => [
         'required',
         'max:255',
         function ($attribute, $value, $fail) {
             if (strtolower($value) != $value) {
                 $fail($attribute.' must be all lowercase.');
             }
         },
     ],
    'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
    'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$request->validate([
    'name' => ['required','string', 'max:255', 'new MyNewRuleClass(or Uppercase)'],
    'email' => ['required', 'string','email','max:255','unique:users'],
    'password' => ['required','string','min:6','confirmed'],
]);
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks! JUST got it to work thanks to @N Mahurin s comment.